# Qt C++ QString to QByteArray Conversion

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qbytearray

I have created an encrypt/decrypt program, when encrypting I store the encrypted QByteArray in a text file.

When trying to decrypt I retrieved it and then put it into the decryption method, the problem is that I need a way to convert it to QByteArray **without changing the format**, otherwise it will not decrypt properly. What I mean is if the file gave me an encrypted value of 1234 and I converted that to QByteArray by going `1234.toLatin1()` it changes the value and the decryption does not work. Any suggestions?

My Code:

```
QFile file(filename);
    QString encrypted;
    QString content;

    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QTextStream stream( &file );
        content = stream.readAll();
    }

    encrypted = content.replace("\n", "");

    qDebug() << encrypted; // Returns correct encrypted value

    QByteArray a;
    a += encrypted;

    qDebug() << "2 " + a; // Returns different value than previous qDebug()

    QByteArray decrypted = crypto.Decrypt(a, key);
    return decrypted;
```

Comment: How did you write QByteArray into the text file?Use QTextStream or just use QFile::write?

Comment: @Daniel QTextStream

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I guess you should use:

```
QString::fromUtf8(const QByteArray &str)
```

Or:

```
QString::QString(const QByteArray &ba)
```

to convert QByteArray to QString, then write it into file by QTextStream.
After that, read file by QTextStream, use:

```
QString::toUtf8()
```

to convert QString to QByteArray.

> QString::QString(const QByteArray &ba)
>
> Constructs a string initialized with the byte array ba. The given byte array is converted to Unicode **using fromUtf8()**.

P.S:
Maybe use QFile::write and QFile::read is a better way.

Comment: I'd rather use QString::fromUtf8 directly instead of implicit QString<->QByteArray conversions, to make the conversion between plain data and unicode explicit and to state the assumed encoding of the data.

Comment: This is the opposite direction from what the title says, for people looking up a similar question...

Answer (score 12):

Try using `QString::toUtf8()`. It works fine for me.

The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#toUtf8) says

> `QByteArray QString::toUtf8() const`
> Returns a UTF-8 representation of the string as a QByteArray.
> UTF-8 is a Unicode codec and can represent all characters in a Unicode string like QString.

Comment: `toUtf8()` is probably a better option because it can handle all of the characters that `QString` can.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toUtf8

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the text from the file is store in the QString content. I think you could create a new QByteArray. Because the constructor of a QByteArray does not allow a QString as input, I will probably have to append the QString to the empty QByteArray.

```
//After if:  
QByteArray tempContent();
tempContent.append(content);
QByteArray decrypted = crypto.Decrypt(tempContent, key);
```

I do not have much experience in the Qt library, but I hope this helps.

Comment: This did convert succesfully but after testing it returned                          `?\x01?YJ?l?p3&?\x11\x1Bv/?X??c?U?~{?a??`                                      and it should be                                                                                        `?\u0001?YJ?l?p3&?\u0011\u001Bv/?X??c?U?~{?a??`                     Why might the value be changing? since I used qDebug() and `content` before creating the `QByteArray` is the correct value

Comment: I've edited my post and added my whole function if it helps

Comment: No idea why this has downvotes, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: This does an ASCII or Latin1 encoding conversion implicitly so unicode won't work with it. Hence the reason Qt allows this constructor to be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply go with  `b64 = data.toUtf8().toBase64();`

First convert it to **QByteArray** with the `toUtf8()` and then immediately convert it to `toBase64()`

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way  :

```
   QByteArray ba;
   QString qs = "String";
   ba += qs;
```

More hard way:

```
QByteArray ba;
QDataStream in(&ba, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
in << QString("String");
```

Extreme way, for people who want to use QBuffer:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QBuffer>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QString>
#include <qcoreapplication.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   QByteArray byteArray;
   QBuffer buffer(&byteArray);
   buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
   QDataStream in( &buffer );
   in << QString("String");
   buffer.close();

   for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length(); ++i) {
      printf("%c - %x\n", byteArray.at(i), byteArray.at(i));
   }

   printf("\n");
   

return a.exec();
}
```

Who run last code can ask me where does the null byte come from?

`QDataStream` serializes the `QString` as a little-endian. 4 bytes are read to create the 32-bit length value, followed by the string itself in UTF-16. This string length in UTF-16 is 12 bytes, so the first three bytes in `QByteArray` will be zero.

There is often a problem with reading the `QByteArray` in `qDebug ()`  The recording is fine.
Don't forget to remove `QT_NO_CAST_FROM_BYTEARRAY` in your `.pro` file, if it has