# Convert QByteArray to QString

Tags: c++, utf-8, qt5, qstring, qbytearray

I want to encrypt the data of a database and to do this, I used AES_128 in  [this link](https://github.com/bricke/Qt-AES) for encryption.

The result of encryption is a QByteArray and the QByteArray is saved on the text file in the correct shape and I could decode it correctly, but and I need to convert it to the QString and reverse to QByteArray to store and read it on the Sqlite DB. I tried some options like

`QByteArray encodedText; QString DataAsString = QString(encodedText);`

and

`string DataAsString1 = encodedText.toStdString();`

and

`QString DataAsString = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8") >toUnicode(encodedText);`

and other solutions like [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802575/qt-c-qstring-to-qbytearray-conversion), but the outputs of these options aren't in the correct way. Because after casting, I couldn't convert the encoded text to decoded correctly.

This is the input string of encoded text:
"\x14r\xF7""6#\xFE\xDB\xF0""D\x1B\xB5\x10\xEDx\xE1""F"
and these are the outputs for the different options:
\024r�6#���D\033�\020�x�F
and
\024rï¿½6#ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½D\033ï¿½\020ï¿½xï¿½F

Does anybody suggestion about the right conversion?

Comment: Normally you'd try a specialized binary to text encoding such as base 64. Currently it seems you are trying to perform binary to text as a *character decoding* operation. However, the randomized bytes within the ciphertext are not representing text at all.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes Maybe I explained in wrong way. At this moment I want to convert the QArrayByte to QString. After encoding, for some string, the output of the encoding is "\x14r\xF7""6#\xFE\xDB\xF0""D\x1B\xB5\x10\xEDx\xE1""F",
while it change after conversion to QString, the output change to \024r�6#���D\033�\020�x�F .

Comment: As nobody could help, I asked this question again in the qt forum and shared the result with you.
[This is the link.](https://forum.qt.io/topic/140679/convert-qbytearray-to-qstring)

Comment: Yes, instead of using a specialized binary to text encoding you can also just store it as binary. News at eleven.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this:
`QString QString::fromUtf8(const QByteArray &str)`

Comment: It didn't work.